# EasClientDeviceInformation.Id in Windows Phone 8.1 (IGetDeviceUniqueIDWrapper?)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

`EasClientDeviceInformation` has been made available to the new Windows Runtime apps (including Windows Phone 8.1), but `EasClientDeviceInformation.Id` does not seem to be available.

In the documentation, I see the `IGetDeviceUniqueIDWrapper`, which seems to be exactly what I need, but I don't seem to see anything which actually returns an object of this interface. I've searched the documentation for the interface and nothing has returned.

Does anyone know how to get the right object of this interface?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id.aspx), `EasClientDeviceInformation` does seem to be available on Phone, but `EasClientDeviceInformation.Id` does not.  Other members of the class *are* available though, so it's not completely useless.

For generating a unique ID, you might have more luck using something like an [ASHWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx).